# Website thehill.com uses lots of CPU resources. Where do I start to investigate?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, chromium, webkit

On Chrome **and** Safari, any page that I load from **thehill.com** will cause cpu usage to increase sharply and stay there.  How would I go about in trying to notify this problem?  i.e. a Chromium developers group, **thehill.com** about page?

I'm familiar with the "Developer Tools", is there some information I can get from there?

IMO It's probably crappy programming by **thehill.com**'s developers, but finding a way to get to him seems impossible.

PS: This is not a programming question, but it may turn into one and I'll go to Stack Overflow then.

Comment: FYI, it does *not* use CPU in TOR (Firefox-based) browser. Usage is zero after loading in ~1 second.

Comment: It uses some CPU (and a bit more than I would like) in standard Firefox. It would be worth contacting the developers if you can

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my first post. Are issues like this simply not worth pursuing?  This is just amateur work for me but is there is perhaps value in pursuing this matter.

Comment: Try it with a good ad blocker. Mine doesn't tell me which ads were blocked, but my separate tracker protector says no trackers were attempted to load (which is a reasonable start). That leaves ads as being the cause.